# Where can I find a list of the languages supported by Ubuntu in the UI?

Tags: gui, language-support, locale

Where can I find a list of the languages supported by Ubuntu in the UI?

I find this list https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=language-pack but it strikes me as incomplete because there is no zh. It seems the language codes end after `g`.

Here is a list of all the valid Locales: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man3/DateTime::Locale::Catalog.3pm.html  My concern is that the valid locales doesn't actually corespond to language presence in the User Interface.

And here is a list release languages from version 9.10 with their percentages of completion. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Translations/ReleaseLanguages/9.10 Is there anything more current?

I am specifically looking for information related to 22.04 but a great answer would help me know how to look in the various Ubuntu versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplest way: Open the **Language Support** tool and click the *Install / Remove Languages...* button. There is the list of supported languages in the Ubuntu version you are using.

Note that translations into those languages are not always well covered. But at least, by installing a language and make it your display language, it may be a bit easier to find your way — assuming that you speak that language, of course.

*Edit:*

If you don't have installed Ubuntu yet, you can

- Go to https://translations.launchpad.net/ubuntu/
- Click the "View all languages" link
- Click the "Status" title

That will give you a list of languages, sorted by translation coverage. Typically the languages with highest coverage are supported languages in the sense that Ubuntu provides language packs.

It may seem that most languages have rather poor translation coverage. But in practice a coverage of say 40% may be sufficient to have the graphical applications decently translated. Much of the strings which are included in the total are from command line tools and various backend software.

Comment: This is a great method if one has access to the software and it is installed. While not clear in the original question, I am look for documentation on software I do not currently have installed.

Comment: @Hugh: I edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky question to answer because translations are performed by a lot of disparate teams. The Gnome Desktop team has their translators (with contributions from all over the globe), the Ubuntu team has their translators, Debian has their translators, and then there are the individual applications.

That said, you can find a more complete list of locales in the `/usr/share/locale` directory. On my 22.04 LTS system, the following 207 are found:

|  | Language (Region) |
| --- | --- |
| `aa` | Afar |
| `ab` | Abkhazian |
| `ace` | Achinese |
| `ach` | Acoli |
| `af` | Afrikaans |
| `ak` | Akan |
| `am` | Amharic |
| `an` | Aragonese |
| `ar` | Arabic |
| `arn` | Mapudungun; Mapuche |
| `ary` | Moroccan Arabic |
| `as` | Assamese |
| `ast` | Asturian; Bable; Leonese; Asturleonese |
| `ay` | Aymara |
| `az` | Azerbaijani |
| `ba` | Bashkir |
| `bar` |  |
| `be` | Belarusian |
| `be@latin` | Belarusian (Latin Character Set) |
| `bem` | Bemba |
| `bg` | Bulgarian |
| `bi` | Bislama |
| `bn` | Bengali |
| `bn_BD` | Bengali (Bangladesh) |
| `bn_IN` | Bengali (India) |
| `bo` | Tibetan |
| `br` | Breton |
| `bs` | Bosnian |
| `byn` | Blin; Bilin |
| `ca` | Catalan |
| `ca@valencia` | Catalan (Valencian) |
| `ce` | Chechen |
| `ch` | Chamorro |
| `chr` | Cherokee |
| `ckb` | Central Kurdish |
| `co` | Corsican |
| `crh` | Crimean Tatar; Crimean Turkish |
| `cs` | Czech |
| `csb` | Kashubian |
| `cv` | Chuvash |
| `cy` | Welsh |
| `da` | Danish |
| `de` | German |
| `de_DE` | German (Germany) |
| `dv` | Divehi; Dhivehi; Maldivian |
| `dz` | Dzongkha |
| `ee` | Ewe |
| `el` | Greek |
| `en` | English |
| `en@boldquot` | English |
| `en@quot` | English |
| `en@shaw` | English |
| `en_AU` | English (Australia) |
| `en_CA` | English (Canada) |
| `en_GB` | English (United Kingdom) |
| `eo` | Esperanto |
| `es` | Spanish |
| `et` | Estonian |
| `eu` | Basque |
| `fa` | Persian |
| `fa_AF` | Persian (Dari) |
| `ff` | Fulah |
| `fi` | Finnish |
| `fil` | Filipino |
| `fo` | Faroese |
| `fr` | French |
| `fr_CA` | French (Canada) |
| `frp` | Franco-Provençal |
| `fur` | Friulian |
| `fy` | Western Frisian |
| `ga` | Irish |
| `gd` | Gaelic; Scottish Gaelic |
| `gez` | Geez |
| `gl` | Galician |
| `gn` | Guarani |
| `gu` | Gujarati |
| `gv` | Manx |
| `ha` | Hausa |
| `haw` | Hawaiian |
| `he` | Hebrew |
| `hi` | Hindi |
| `hr` | Croatian |
| `ht` | Haitian; Haitian Creole |
| `hu` | Hungarian |
| `hy` | Armenian |
| `ia` | Interlingua |
| `id` | Indonesian |
| `io` | Ido |
| `is` | Icelandic |
| `it` | Italian |
| `iu` | Inuktitut |
| `ja` | Japanese |
| `jam` | Jamaican Creole English |
| `jv` | Javanese |
| `ka` | Georgian |
| `kab` | Kabyle |
| `ki` | Kikuyu; Gikuyu |
| `kk` | Kazakh |
| `kl` | Kalaallisut; Greenlandic |
| `km` | Central Khmer |
| `kmr` | Northern Kurdish |
| `kn` | Kannada |
| `ko` | Korean |
| `kok` | Konkani |
| `ku` | Kurdish |
| `kv` | Komi |
| `kw` |  |
| `ky` | Kirghiz; Kyrgyz |
| `lb` | Luxembourgish; Letzeburgesch |
| `lg` | Ganda |
| `ln` | Lingala |
| `lo` | Lao |
| `lt` | Lithuanian |
| `lv` | Latvian |
| `mai` | Maithili |
| `mg` | Malagasy |
| `mhr` | Eastern Mari |
| `mi` | Māori |
| `mjw` | Karbi |
| `mk` | Macedonian |
| `ml` | Malayalam |
| `mn` | Mongolia |
| `mnw` | Mon |
| `mo` |  |
| `mr` | Marāṭhī |
| `ms` | Malay |
| `mt` | Maltese |
| `my` | Burmese |
| `na` | Nauruan |
| `nah` |  |
| `nb` | Norwegian (Bokmål) |
| `nb_NO` | Norwegian (Bokmål) (Norway) |
| `nds` | Low German; Low Saxon |
| `ne` | Nepali |
| `nl` | Dutch |
| `nn` | Norwegian Nynorsk |
| `nso` | Northern Sotho; Pedi; Sepedi |
| `nv` | Navajo; Navaho |
| `oc` | Occitan |
| `om` | Oromo |
| `or` | Oriya |
| `os` | Ossetian; Ossetic |
| `pa` | Punjabi; Panjabi |
| `pam` | Kapampangan; Pampanga |
| `pap` | Papiamento |
| `pi` | Pāli |
| `pl` | Polish |
| `pms` | Piemontese |
| `ps` | Pashto; Pushto |
| `pt` | Portugese |
| `pt_BR` | Portugese (Brazil) |
| `pt_PT` | Portugese (Portugal) |
| `qu` | Quechua |
| `ro` | Romanian |
| `ru` | Russian |
| `rw` | Kinyarwanda |
| `sa` | Sanskrit |
| `sc` | Sardinian |
| `sco` | Scots |
| `sd` | Sindhi |
| `se` | Northern Sami |
| `shn` | Shan |
| `si` | Sinhala; Sinhalese |
| `sk` | Slovak |
| `sl` | Slovenian |
| `so` | Somali |
| `son` |  |
| `sq` | Albanian |
| `sr` | Serbian |
| `sr@Latn` | Serbian (Latin Characters (*with a typo?*)) |
| `sr@latin` | Serbian (Latin Characters) |
| `st` | Southern Sotho |
| `sv` | Swedish |
| `sw` | Swahili |
| `szl` | Silesian |
| `ta` | Tamil |
| `ta_LK` | Tamil (Sri Lanka) |
| `te` | Telugu |
| `tg` | Tagalog |
| `th` | Thai |
| `ti` | Tigrinya |
| `tig` | Tigre |
| `tk` | Turkmen |
| `tl` | Tagalog |
| `tr` | Turkish |
| `trv` | Taroko |
| `tt` | Tatar |
| `tt@iqtelif` | Tatar (İQTElif Character Set) |
| `tzm` | Central Atlas Tamazight |
| `ug` | Uighur; Uyghur |
| `uk` | Ukrainian |
| `ur` | Urdu |
| `uz` | Uzbek |
| `ve` | Venda |
| `vec` | Venetian |
| `vi` | Vietnamese |
| `wa` | Walloon |
| `wal` | Wolaitta; Wolaytta |
| `wo` | Wolof |
| `xh` | Xhosa |
| `yo` | Yoruba |
| `zh_CN` | Chinese (China) |
| `zh_HK` | Chinese (Hong Kong) |
| `zh_Hans` | Chinese (Simplified) |
| `zh_Hant` | Chinese (Traditional) |
| `zh_TW` | Chinese (Taiwan Province of China) |
| `zu` | Zulu |

<sup>**Note:** Codes that do not have a corresponding name are languages outside of my resources. Feel free to fill in the blanks if you know what they are.</sup>

Many of these languages are in need of volunteers to fill in gaps in the common UI elements, such as Gnome applications and installation wizards.

Please also note that just because these locales contain *some* definitions on many installations does not mean the language sets are actually installed. Be sure to use the Language Support section of the Settings to install the languages you elect to use on your system.